# How important is it to replace engine torque mount? (have pic)

Tags: buick, motor-mounts

I just bought a 2007 Buick Lucerne.  The rubber in the engine torque mount has separated into two pieces. How important is it to replace the mount?  If I do decide to replace it, is the job as straight forward as it seems?  I imagine I'd just have to remove the two bolts, slide the old one off and slide the new one on.

[image: Engine Mount Close-up]

[image: Engine Mount Overview]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The torque mount is fairly important. It keeps everything in place when the engine is trying to torque over from either a launch or a stop. While this one isn't *completely* shot, it needs to be replaced before that happens, so as to not cause issues in other areas of the vehicle. It will eventually affect the other motor mounts (because they have to do the job the torque mount is doing right now ... pick up its slack, let's say). It also causes stress on the exhaust system due to the extra flexing going on.

As far as replacement, you are exactly right. This should be a straight remove/replace operation. As long as your other mounts are in good shape still, you shouldn't have any issues. You may want to ensure you have a long, thin bladed screwdriver to help you get it aligned during installation. Other than that, just make sure you have the same bolts in the same holes and you're golden. (**NOTE:** Each bolt doesn't have to go into the exact hole it came out of: if you have two bolts/nuts which are exactly the same, they can be swapped. I'm just suggesting not to put the wrong size bolts in the wrong holes -- that could get ugly.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the answer. I just did mine - looks like the highlighted dogbone in the picture above.

Use 18MM socket, preferable deep well.

The rearmost end has a stud and a nut, the front end has a long bolt.

Remove them both - and lift the torque strut off of the stud, and the whole thing easily lifts out.

Place the new one in position and replace the nut and the bolt.

Don't over torque the bolt or the rubber bushing will be distorted.
You are done.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed mine in a 2007 Lucerne CXS.
Remove water overflow bottle, 2x 10mm nuts and one plastic fastener.
Remove two 18mm fasteners, one bolt (front) one nut (rear).
Remove arm.
Replace in reverse sequence.
Take care to see position of wiring and other routing as you remove and replace arm. Take care to not overtorque front bolt into aluminum bracket. Deep well 18mm is required for rear nut. Lower water tank nut requires 10mm on short flexible.
(Covering Fuse Panel and Jump Terminal with non-conducting barrier is recommended while working around area.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t replace the damaged torque strut right away, the next thing that will happen is the front motor mount will break. I went through 3 front motor mounts on my Lucerne before finding out that the torque strut was broken inside. Seems like a common problem on Buick Lucernes as they could only find one new replacement  motor mount at a GM Dealership on the other side of the country.